# Need assistance with the JWT authenticate process

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, token

I am working on a user login project. My front end is React, and my server side is Node/Express js. I am trying to learn about JWT to create protected routes. However, I have gotten stuck when it comes to sending my token (already successfully generated) back to my front end application. I am trying to store the token in a cookie, then send that back to my react side. It is my understanding that I must store the token on the react side before I can access a protected route on my server side, but I am at a loss as to how to proceed to accomplish this. Here is my code for the login post request on my server:

```
app.post('/userLogin', function(req, res) {
    var {usernameLogin, passwordLogin} = req.query;
    console.log(req.query);
    var validateLogin = `SELECT CustomerID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Username='${usernameLogin}' AND Password='${passwordLogin}'`;
    mysqlConnection.query(validateLogin, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            // Checks to see if the result object (CustomerID) exists or not.
           if(Object.entries(result).length === 0) {
               console.log('sorry');
           } else {
               console.log(result);
               console.log('existing');

               const token = jwt.sign({ usernameLogin: usernameLogin}, 'loginKey');
               res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true}).sendStatus(200);
               console.log(token);
           }
        } 
    });
});
```

and this is my react onSubmit (called login) in my react app. Just as a side note, the "it worked" message successfully is printed to the console, but this is the point at which I do not know how to retrieve and store the token on my client side for future use to access protected routes:

```
login = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/userLogin?usernameLogin=' + this.state.usernameLogin +
          '&passwordLogin=' + this.state.passwordLogin, {method: 'POST'}
    )
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log("it worked!!!");

      } else {
        console.log('there was a problem at line 27');
      }
    })
  };
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the client side, you can store the token returned from server side using **localStorage** property.

Example to set the item: `localStorage.setItem("token", <token>);`

Example to get the item: `let token = localStorage.getItem("token");`

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Local_storage

PS: Let me know if was enough to solve your question.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! If I was able to accept two answers, I would have accepted yours as well! Your idea with the local storage was much better than the cookies, and the documentation you provided was very helpful (I seem to struggle finding good documentation). Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, was a pleasure to help you.